# Neural network input size in opencv::dnn

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to determine (dynamically) the image size expected as input of a deep neural network model that is loaded with the dnn module of opencv. For instance, if I load a caffe model, I first have:

```
cv::Mat img = imread("my_image.jpg");
cv::dnn::Net m_net;
m_net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe("my_prototxt","my_model");

int img_size; // TODO how to determine it ?

cv::Mat blob =  cv::dnn::blobFromImage(img, 1.0, cv::Size(img_size, img_size));
m_net.setInput(blob);
cv::Mat res = m_net.forward("layer_name");
```

My problem is to determine `img_size` from `m_net` here. I guess it should be feasible with `dnn::getLayersShapes` but I do not understand what is supposed to be the first argument in my case.

I give here the example of a caffe model, but I am interested in being able to do the same with a tensorflow, darknet or torch model as well.

Comment: thr 2nd parametet. a vector of MatShapes should give you the dimensions. Probably first anf second int in there will be with and height and the third one the number of channels. But I didnt test it mysrlf yet, so just try

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My problem is that I have no idea of what should be the first parameter of `getLayersShapes` and I do not find any example. I just want the information, what am I supposed to provide for this but the network ?

Comment: sorry, would have to test it myself. Maybe you can have a look at opencv dnn source code?

Comment: Actually the problem is that `getLayersShapes` seems to need the "shape input blob in net input layer"... That is precisely what I want to determine automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the *".prototext"* file that comes with the caffe model, it states the required input sizes. (Haven't used models other than caffe ones)

Setting correct input size is the responsibility of the user, as some network architectures, eg. fully-connected feedforward networks require exact size inputs, while architectures like CNN's do not and can work on arbitrary sizes of input images.

[image]